# Expectation of the product between two dependent Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

I have two dependent Bernoulli random variables $X$ and $Y$, and I know that:

$$
\begin{align}
P(X=0)&=P(X=1)=1/2 \\
P(Y=1)&=11/24 \\
P(Y=0|X=0)&=1/3 \\
P(Y=1|X=1)&=1/4 \\
\end{align}
$$

Is it possible to get the expectation $\mathbb{E}[XY]$?

Comment: Begin by transforming $P(A|B)$ into $P(A \cap B)/P(B)$

Comment: Two thoughts to hep you get started: (a) can you list out all possible pairs of values of $X$ and $Y$ together? E.g. (1) $X=0, Y=0$, (2) $X=0, Y=1$, etc....; and (b) for each pair, can you figure out its probability?

Comment: As $XY=0$ unless $X=1$ and $Y=1$ it's sufficient to calculate $P(X=1\land Y=1)$, which is obviously $1/8$.

Comment: Hello @JeanMarie roundsquare and MichaelHope thank you very much for the suggestion. Which formula links the expected value $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ and the probability $P(X=1 \cap Y=1)$?

Answer (score 0):

To address the question in light of the good comments.

Let $Z:=XY$ then $P(Z=1)+P(Z=0) = 1$.

As Michael Hoppe pointed out $Z=1 \implies X=Y=1$ so there is only one probability to calculate $P(X=1\cap Y=1) = P(Y=1|X=1)P(X=1) =1/4 \cdot 1/2 =1/8 = P(Z=1)$

Now,
$$E[XY]=E[Z] = 0\cdot P(Z=0) + 1\cdot P(Z=1) = P(Z=1)= 1/8$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $X\sim\operatorname{B}\left(1, \frac12\right)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{B}\left(1, \frac{11}{24}\right)$, then
$$R_{XY}=\{0, 1\}\implies XY\sim\operatorname{B}\left(1, p\right)$$
Where $R_{XY}$ denotes the support of $XY$ and
$$p=P(Y=1\mid X=1)P(X=1)=\frac18$$
Note that the [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution), $\operatorname{Bern}(p)$ or $\operatorname{B}(1, p)$, of a random variable has an expected value of $p$. In our case, $p=\frac18$. Therefore,
$$\operatorname{E}\left[XY\right]=\frac18$$
So yes, as others already mentioned, it is indeed possible to get $\operatorname{E}\left[XY\right]$.